# Docker-Compose SSR App, Request from server and Request from browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm doing the following deployment (docker-compose), which consists of a front-end with Nuxt (SSR) and a back-end with Django:

**Deployment**

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    restart: always
    build: ./task_processor_back
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file: .env
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn task_processor.wsgi:application -w 2  -b :8000
    
  frontend:
    restart: always
    build: ./task_processor_front
    expose:
      - "3500"
    depends_on:
      - "backend"
    links:
      - backend
    command: npm start
```

I'm making use of the nuxtServerInit function that calls the back-end API, via Axios.

**NuxtServerInit**

```
// store/index.ts
import { Dispatch } from 'vuex';

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }: { dispatch: Dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('tasks/fetchTasks', true); #ends with a call to Axios
  }
};
```

**Other Axios Call**

```
// store/task.ts
@Action
  async sendReply(reply: Reply) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      TaskProcessor.sendReply(reply)
        .then(() => resolve())
        .catch(() => reject());
    })
  }
```

The problem arises that when it's deployed through the docker-compose, it creates a network called <project_name_default> through which it can communicate with the other deployed resources (Dockers). I realize that all the calls of the part of the SSR (server) such as the nuxtServerInit function have to be done internally through said network, while the calls of the javascript functions that are executed in the browser have to be made in a external. The above I mean:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
Internal: axios: { baseURL: 'http://backend:8000' } //backend = resource name in docker-compose
External: axios: { baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000' }
```

I could verify this because if I leave the internal configuration it makes the successful call from the nuxtServerInit function but when I go to call from the browser, it does not. Otherwise if I leave the external configuration (and comment the nuxtServerInit function) it works correctly from the browser.

How can I handle these two scenarios in the docker compose?

Comment: Did you find any answers ByteBat?